# REACT - TypeError: wrapper is null

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im building a webpage with react and JS, but right now I have this error thats making my counter go in to the fritz. Making the gadget that im building not following the 3000ms time interval consistently. Here is the code.

```
import React from 'react';
import './portfolio.css';

const rand = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

  const uniqueRand = (min, max, prev) => {
    let next = prev;
    while(prev === next) next = rand(min, max);
    
    return next;
  }
  const combinations = [
    { configuration: 1, roundness: 1 },
    { configuration: 1, roundness: 2 },
    { configuration: 1, roundness: 3 },
    { configuration: 2, roundness: 2 },
    { configuration: 2, roundness: 3 }
  ];

  let prev = 0;

  
const Portfolio = () => {

  const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

  setInterval(() => {
    const index = uniqueRand(0, combinations.length - 1, prev),
          combination = combinations[index];
    
    wrapper.dataset.configuration = combination.configuration;
    wrapper.dataset.roundness = combination.roundness;
    
    prev = index;
  }, 3000);
  
  return (
    <div className='RO__portfolio' id='portfolio'>
      <div className='RO__portfolio-content' data-roundness="1" data-configuration ="1" id='wrapper'>
        <div className='RO__portfolio-content_shape'></div>
        <div className='RO__portfolio-content_shape'></div>
        <div className='RO__portfolio-content_shape'></div>
        <div className='RO__portfolio-content_shape'></div>
        <div className='RO__portfolio-content_shape'></div>
        <div className='RO__portfolio-content_shape'></div>
        <div className='RO__portfolio-content_shape'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )

}

export default Portfolio
```

React marks the error in the line:

```
    wrapper.dataset.configuration = combination.configuration;
    wrapper.dataset.roundness = combination.roundness;
```

I have tried mooving this element outside the Portfolio element, but it's giving me the exact same error. I'm missing whats happening here. I'm new with react

Comment: The element is not in the view when you try to find it. You need to investigate the `useRef` hook.

Comment: This-> https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef#useref

Comment: *"document.getElementById("wrapper")"* - In React this is pretty much **always** the wrong approach.  Whatever you're trying to accomplish, it should probably be using **state** to store/update the data and refer to that state value when rendering the markup.

Comment: This is a very poor usage of React. You're circumventing the whole point of the library and breaking the core rules, like not mutating state. I suggest reading the docs and working through tutorials so you understand the fundamental principles of React before moving forward.

Comment: You are mutating (*attempting*) the DOM outside any React component lifecycle and breaking other React rules, I'm not surprised the code has issues. The `"wrapper"` element can't be accessed until the component as rendered once to the DOM. Don't query the DOM, use a React ref to access DOMNodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `configuration` and `roundness` are supposed to do...

But to change them in the `dataset` property of the DOM element every 3 seconds, you need `useRef` and `useEffect` hooks.
I suggest you read more [here](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html).

One is to retain the reference to the DOM element, as others mentionned.
And the second is to retain a refence to the `setInterval` to avoid having more than one interval running...

Try the code below:
Have a look at it running on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-interval-for-so-question-75120536-qniord?file=/src/Portfolio.js:0-1933) → Open the console!

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
// import './portfolio.css'; // Commented out because it was not provided on SO

const rand = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

const uniqueRand = (min, max, prev) => {
  let next = prev;
  while (prev === next) next = rand(min, max);

  return next;
};
const combinations = [
  { configuration: 1, roundness: 1 },
  { configuration: 1, roundness: 2 },
  { configuration: 1, roundness: 3 },
  { configuration: 2, roundness: 2 },
  { configuration: 2, roundness: 3 }
];

let prev = 0;

const Portfolio = () => {
  const wrapperRef = useRef();

  const interval = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    let wrapper = wrapperRef.current;

    if (interval.current) {
      clearInterval(interval.current);
    }

    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
      const index = uniqueRand(0, combinations.length - 1, prev),
        combination = combinations[index];

      wrapper.dataset.configuration = combination.configuration;
      wrapper.dataset.roundness = combination.roundness;

      console.log({
        configuration: wrapper.dataset.configuration,
        roundness: wrapper.dataset.roundness
      });
      prev = index;
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="RO__portfolio" id="portfolio">
      <div
        className="RO__portfolio-content"
        data-roundness="1"
        data-configuration="1"
        id="wrapper"
        ref={wrapperRef}
      >
        <div className="RO__portfolio-content_shape"></div>
        <div className="RO__portfolio-content_shape"></div>
        <div className="RO__portfolio-content_shape"></div>
        <div className="RO__portfolio-content_shape"></div>
        <div className="RO__portfolio-content_shape"></div>
        <div className="RO__portfolio-content_shape"></div>
        <div className="RO__portfolio-content_shape"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Portfolio;
```

Notice `ref={wrapperRef}` to get the DOM reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a step back and think about what your code does.

First, your user navigates to the page, and this function component is called.

Your code looks in the document for the element with the id "wrapper".  It doesn't exist yet.

Later on, your function returns some JSX, causing the element with the id "wrapper" to come into existence.  Now, "wrapper" exists.

However, since the earlier code ran before "wrapper" exists, it wasn't stored in the variable.

You could solve this from a number of ways; the others have suggested useRef.